# How to get label index on click in RGraph

Tags: javascript, angular, rgraph

I am using RGraph in our angular 7 application.
and able to show the 3d graphs and all.

1. I have a requirement to get index when user clicks on x axis labels.
2. Some times not able to update the graph data dynamically.(this issue is producing in when we deploy code in server but as a developer I have to fix it.)
   please find in the below image.[image]

3. Is it good way to remove and add same 3d graph for every user action so that overlapping will not come again.
4. I need x axis title and y axis title also.

If any one know kindly help me.

Answer (score 0):

1.That's possible for a 2D chart by using two charts - the second positioned over the labels of the first. See this example:

https://codepen.io/rgraph/full/poEJKKm

There's an example of a 3D chart there too with the axes enabled.

```
<script>
    labels = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];

    bar = new RGraph.Bar({
      id:'cvs',
      data: [8,4,6,3,5,4,2,8,6,4,2,2],
      options: {
          marginInner: 10,
          xaxisLabels: labels,
          xaxis: false,
          yaxis: false,
          backgroundGridVlines: false,
          backgroundGridBorder: false
      }
    }).draw();

    bar2 = new RGraph.Bar({
      id:'cvs',
      data: [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
        options: {
            xaxis: false,
            yaxis: false,
            backgroundGrid: false,
            marginBottom: 10,
            marginTop: 215,
            colors: ['transparent'],
            variantThreedXaxis: false,
            variantThreedYaxis: false,
            yaxisScale: false,
            tooltips: '\0',
            tooltipsHighlight: false
        }
    }).draw().on('click', function (e, shape)
    {
        alert(shape.dataset);
    });
</script>
    
    
    
    

    bar = new RGraph.Bar({
      id:'cvs2',
      data: [8,4,6,3,5,4,2,8,6,4,2,2],
      options: {
          variant: '3d',
          marginInner: 10,
          xaxisLabels: labels
      }
    }).draw();
```

(Use the "change view" button to see the code)

2. Updating is just a case of setting the new data on the object:

myBar.data = [4,8,6,3,5,4,8,7,8,4,6,9];

And then calling the redraw method:

RGraph.redraw();

If you don't call the redraw method it won't change.

3. If you removing the chart from the ObjectRegistry too and there's not 1000 user actions then I suppose it would be OK. You can clear the ObjectRegistry with:

RGraph.ObjectRegistry.clear();

4. There are properties for that:

https://www.rgraph.net/canvas/bar.html#xaxis-properties
https://www.rgraph.net/canvas/bar.html#yaxis-properties

Answer (score 0):

I've been tinkering with this and this code should work on the v5.26 libraries:

```
<script>

    labels = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];

    bar = new RGraph.Bar({
      id:'cvs1',
      data: [8,4,6,3,5,4,2,8,6,4,2,2],
      options: {
          variant: '3d',
          marginInner: 10,
          xaxisLabels: labels,
          backgroundGridVlines: false,
          backgroundGridBorder: false
      }
    }).draw();

    bar2 = new RGraph.Bar({
      id:'cvs1',
      data: [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
      options: {
        xaxis: false,
        yaxis: false,
        backgroundGrid: false,
        marginBottom: 10,
        marginTop: 215,
        colors: ['transparent'],
        variantThreedXaxis: false,
        variantThreedYaxis: false,
        yaxisScale: false,
        tooltips: '\0',
        tooltipsHighlight: false
      }
    }).draw().on('click', function (e, shape)
    {
        alert(shape.dataset);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Great answer Richard will implement and get back